# Neo4jrb 8.x- Cypher query issues

Tags: cypher, neo4j.rb

I am using a rails app with **neo4j** database, recently I had updated **Neo4j server** from v 2.x to 3.x and the **gem neo4j** from 7.x to 8.x .
Having these models in my app:

```
class Country
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  property :summary, type: String
  property :code, type: String

  has_many :out, :provinces, type: :placed, model_class: :Province
end

class Province
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  property :summary, type: String
  property :code, type: String

  has_one :in, :country, type: :placed, model_class: :Country
end
```

when I try to do a query in this way:

```
Neo4j::Core::Query.new.match(p: Province, c: Country).match("(c)-[PLACED]->(p)").order_by('p.summary').return(:p).pluck(:p)
```

I retrieve this error:

```
 Neo4j::Core::Query.new.match(p: Province, c: Country).match("(c)-[PLACED]->(p)").order_by('p.summary').return(:p).pluck(:p)
NoMethodError: undefined method `_query' for nil:NilClass
```

and in the same way for the other similar queries performed by Neo4j::Core::Query class.

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `neo4j-core` API has changed in the latest versions of the gems.  You should check out the upgrade guide:

http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.x/UpgradeGuide.html